# Retrieve ssm parameter by path and set to ECS task definition in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm creating a task definition with terraform and the containers need a few variables that are stored in SSM parameter store. I'm getting them by path but I when I set them to task definition, I get this error:

creating ECS Task Definition (superset): ClientException: Environment variable name cannot be null or blank

My code

```
data "aws_ssm_parameters_by_path" "superset_prod" {
  path = "/prod/superset/"
  recursive = true
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "superset_task_definition" {
  family                   = "superset"
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.arn
  task_role_arn            = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_role.arn
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  memory                   = 1024
  cpu                      = 512
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"

  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name = local.services.superset_app.service_name
      image     = local.superset_image
      memory    = 1024
      user = "root"
      command = ["/app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh", "app-gunicorn"]
      cpu       = 512
      essential = true
      portMappings = [
        {
          containerPort = local.services.superset_app.port
          hostPort      = local.services.superset_app.port
          protocol      = "tcp"
        }
      ],
      environment = [
        data.aws_ssm_parameters_by_path.superset_prod

      ]
      secrets = []
      logConfiguration = {
        logDriver = "awsfirelens",
        options = {
          Name               = "es"
          Cloud_ID           = var.elastic_cloud_id
          Index              = "filebeat-8.6.1"
          tls                = "On"
          "tls.verify"       = "Off"
          Tag_Key            = "tags"
          Include_Tag_Key    = "true"
          Retry_Limit        = "10"
          Suppress_Type_Name = "On"
          Trace_Output       = "On" # DEBUG
          Trace_Error        = "On" # DEBUG
          Replace_Dots       = "On"
        }
        secretOptions = []
      },
      mountPoints = [],
      volumesFrom = [],
      dependsOn   = []
    },
  tags = {
    environment = local.environment
  }
}
```

How can I set all the parameters in the environment variable for the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, I would say you want to use the ARNs of the parameters directly, something like the following:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "superset_task_definition" {
  family                   = "superset"
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.arn
  task_role_arn            = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_role.arn
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  memory                   = 1024
  cpu                      = 512
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"

  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name = local.services.superset_app.service_name
      image     = local.superset_image
      memory    = 1024
      user = "root"
      command = ["/app/docker/docker-bootstrap.sh", "app-gunicorn"]
      cpu       = 512
      essential = true
      portMappings = [
        {
          containerPort = local.services.superset_app.port
          hostPort      = local.services.superset_app.port
          protocol      = "tcp"
        }
      ],
      secrets = [
        {
          name = "<environment_variable_name>"
          valueFrom = "arn:aws:ssm:<region>:<aws_account_id>:parameter/<parameter_name>"
        }
      ]
      logConfiguration = {
        logDriver = "awsfirelens",
        options = {
          Name               = "es"
          Cloud_ID           = var.elastic_cloud_id
          Index              = "filebeat-8.6.1"
          tls                = "On"
          "tls.verify"       = "Off"
          Tag_Key            = "tags"
          Include_Tag_Key    = "true"
          Retry_Limit        = "10"
          Suppress_Type_Name = "On"
          Trace_Output       = "On" # DEBUG
          Trace_Error        = "On" # DEBUG
          Replace_Dots       = "On"
        }
        secretOptions = []
      },
      mountPoints = [],
      volumesFrom = [],
      dependsOn   = []
    },
  tags = {
    environment = local.environment
  }
}
```

You would of course have to do this for all the environment variables you need.

Bear in mind that the task role needs to have [properly defined permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/secrets-envvar-ssm-paramstore.html) for this to work.

Comment: So, I have to set the variable one by one, I can't set all the variable that I get with the get_parameter_by_path?

Comment: How would the container know to which environment variable to map it to if not using one by one?